# Looking for source/list/documenation of Apple Bluetooth Services & UUIDs, like Apple Continuity, Apple Nearby

Tags: ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I am working on a bluetooth-scanning app, and I am showing the names of the standard bluetooth services and characteristics, e.g.

180A - Device Information

As defined in the official bluetooth specifications (https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/assigned-numbers/).

I have figured out that Apple-Devices (iPhone, Apple Watch, etc) share a lot of services, and these two show up regularly.

```
"D0611E78-BBB4-4591-A5F8-487910AE4366": "Apple Continuity"
"9FA480E0-4967-4542-9390-D343DC5D04AE": "Apple Nearby"
```

I want to show data for these too, but I am having lots of difficulties finding information on this.

Is there a source or list that shows all of these? Are there more?